# Is there a way to keep data from previous recursion in C++ (specific example)?

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I'm working on an AVL Tree Project (almost finished after lots of hours of programming) and I wonder if it's possible to keep data from the calling recursion. This is the code:

```
node* previous;

//Visits the nodes by level recursively (post-order traversal), so that it can calculate the balance of each node (updates heights when deleting a node with two children)
void AVLTree::updateTreeHeights(node *ptr)
{
if(ptr==root)
    previous=root;
if(ptr==NULL)
    return;
updateTreeHeights(ptr->leftChild);
updateTreeHeights(ptr->rightChild);
if(ptr->leftChild==NULL && ptr->rightChild==NULL)
{
    ptr->heightL=ptr->heightR=0;
}
else if(ptr->leftChild==NULL)
{
    ptr->heightR=max(ptr->rightChild->heightL,ptr->rightChild->heightR)+1;
    ptr->heightL=0;
}
else if(ptr->rightChild==NULL)
{
    ptr->heightL=max(ptr->leftChild->heightL,ptr->leftChild->heightR)+1;
    ptr->heightR=0;
}
else
{
    ptr->heightL=max(ptr->leftChild->heightL,ptr->leftChild->heightR)+1;
    ptr->heightR=max(ptr->rightChild->heightL,ptr->rightChild->heightR)+1;
}
ptr->balance=ptr->heightR-ptr->heightL;
if(ptr->balance>1)
    balanceTree(ptr,previous,ptr->rightChild);
else if(ptr->balance<-1)
    balanceTree(ptr,previous,ptr->leftChild);
```

}

Here's what I want! I want to keep the ptr value from the calling recursion and save it to the gloabal variable named previous (it's not necessery to be global, but I figured that it must be the only way). For example if ptr points at number 20 and then we call the recursive function for ptr's leftChild (e.g. updateTreeHeights(ptr->leftChild);) I want to keep number 20 (previous=ptr;). Is it possible somehow? I'm not really good with recursion! (Don't tell! :P )

Comment: Do you want to implement an AVL tree that works like a [splay tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. You can make a global variable and then just copy it over from updateTreeHeights. Just keep a look out for making sure the copy happens only once, and also by doing previous=ptr previous will be pointing to the entire node. So you might have to dive a little deeper in the node to get the date you want.

Comment: previous=ptr is fine with me! ;) I don't need the number actually, but its pointer! 
However, when you say copy it over what exactly do you mean? I'm affraid I don't understand. Could you write down this part of the code with your correction please?

Comment: Sure, but where do you want this to happen. For example why do you want this copy to happen. You need to know that in order to decide on where to make the copy in your function.

Comment: I'm assuming you want it after you set the balance.

Comment: Imagine an AVL Tree (like this http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/research/RG/alg/avl.gif) 
The function I posted "visits" the nodes by levels. So when it is at node with number 89 for example, I want previous to point at 84 (see image).

Comment: I want it before I set the balance, because if the balance is >1 or <-1 I want to call the function balanceTree with previous as a parameter. (Sorry I haven't posted this already, I forgot)

Comment: I corrected the code, so that you can see when I need previous. Actually I need the previous node of EACH node! :) Thank tou for your time! I appreciate your help! Hope I can find a sollution!

Comment: Hold on, so I'm trying to understand what you want here. So you want to hold a pointer to the previous node of every node? I thought you wanted just the last node that your function handles.

Comment: I may have understood what you told me! I changed the updateTreeHeights function, so that it has two parameters (ptr and previous ptr) and each time I call it like this: updateTreeHeights(ptr->leftChild,ptr); So I have both the current and the previous node!

Comment: Yes, if you are going to do it that way, you don't need the global variable. If you just pass the previous pointer through the recursive calls then you will have it at the end.